# Setting HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host

Tags: asp.net

I need to replace the host part of the Uri

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host = "newDomain";`

you can't set host.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this to a Uri for reusing it to redirect somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class to change URIs, e.g.

```
var original = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
var changed = (new UriBuilder(original) { Host = "newDomain" }).Uri;
```

URIs are tricky little beasts with plenty of semantics you might not know or expect, so don't go using string functions on them unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: +1 - Didn't even know about this class.  Much better than my string substitution.

Comment: here's how I ended up doing it app.Request.Url.ToString().Replace(host, "domainroot");

Comment: @coffeeaddict - Why would you do it using string replacements when I've pointed out that's a bad idea and given you a one-liner that does it using a proper API?